# Animationlistener, listen to who?

Tags: java, android, animation, listener

I have an activity with several imageViews that are animated. I also have one animationlistener that listens to all my animations. In the animationlistener the methods I can see that an animation object is recived.

The question is how I can know which of my animations are calling the animationlitener (or on which view has the animation ended)? Can I connect an id to my animation object?
Since the numbers of imageviews are dynamic I would prefer to not create a listener to every animation.

Comment: Why do you need to identify the animation object? What do you want to do with it inside the listener?

Comment: I would like to trig new actions on the imageview at the end of the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an Android developer, but I googled "android animationlistener" and got [this API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html).  From the looks of it, I believe the Animation object is passed into the method.  At least, it looks that way to me.

If you need to correlate that to some original instantiation, you could always implement some sort of lookup table using a Map.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyAnimationListener implements Animation.AnimationListener {
    private View mView;

    public MyAnimationListener(View view) {
        mView = view;
    }

    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {}
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
}
```

Comment: If there are several animatinons active at the same time it can be a bit tricky to use this sollution, I think.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the code above,
i have another useful example here :)

```
public void hideSeekbarAnimated() {
    Animation fadeoutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.fadeout);
    fadeoutAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    seekbarPageNavigation.startAnimation(fadeoutAnimation);
}
```

hope it helps, was just looking for the same answer :)